# realpath() doesnt show realpath GitLab ci runner

Tags: php, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

the code is stored in `/var/www/abc` -- "CodePath"

when running gitlab-ci (runner), the code is called via `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/4v8bC1n9/0/_gitlabgroup_/_gitprojectname_/abc` -- "RealPath"

I'm using a local runner and a shell execution.

when I use the `realpath()` function in my php code, it still shows the "CodePath" when using gitlab ci runner, instead of "RealPath".

How can I get the "RealPath" integrated in my code, or reconfig GitLab to use the "CodePath" instead?

Comment: Maybe you do `realpath()` in some VM that actually is `/var/www/abc`?

Comment: I'm using a local runner and a shell execution, so for my understanding it shouldn't be using a vm?

Comment: Is `/var/www/abc` a symlink to your real path?

Comment: it's the real path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to madflow's mentioning of the variable I managed to figure out the following:

runners specific configuration files exist and can be configured as [described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section)

I needed to do these things:

specify enable the `[runners.custom_build_dir]` section in the config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  builds_dir = "/var/www/abc"
[runners.custom_build_dir]
  enabled = true
```

(boolean not in quotes)
specify a variable in my yml

```
variables:
  GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/
```

on os level there was some privilege setting for the dir required, where I went for quick and dirty 777 on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

The runner cli options are documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html#overview

The path where the job is run and your sources are cloned into is available in the environment variable:

`CI_PROJECT_DIR`

> The full path where the repository is cloned and where the job is run. If the GitLab Runner builds_dir parameter is set, this variable is set relative to the value of builds_dir. For more information, see Advanced configuration for GitLab Runner.

You did no state how you use `realpath(path)`...

> Whilst a path must be supplied, the value can be an empty string. In this case, the value is interpreted as the current directory.

So maybe you hardcode `chdir('/var/www/abc');` somewhere?

When you do `chdir(getenv('CI_PROJECT_DIR'));` before you call realpath() - it should use the `CI` directory. Assuming you use `realpath` without a parameter.

Also: maybe you can make some changes and use one of the the built in constants for the current directory: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php